# Arduino TCP communication with Android phone

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, networking, tcpip

I am trying to communicate Arduino Uno with an android phone. What I trying to is:

1. Android device post a string to Arduino
2. Arduino post a integer to Android

So far I can post message from Android, received in Arduino board, but I **can not post a integer to Android, nothing receive at Android**

**Arduino Code** (Which can receive character "a", "b", "c", "d", and for case "z", I would like to send back the distance which is an `int`)  :

```
void loop()
{ 
  distance = Dist.getDistanceCentimeter();
  if(distance<=5 & distance>1)
  {
    back();
    delay(100);
    ting();
    distance=0;
  } 
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    lkf = Serial.read();
  switch(lkf)
  {
  case 'a':
     front();
     servoX.write(90);
     lkf=0;  
     break;   
   case 'b':
     back();
     lkf=0;
     break;     
   case 'c':
     left();
     lkf=0;
     break;
   case 'd':
     right();
     lkf=0;
     break; 
  case 'z':
    Serial.write(distance);
    break; 
    }
  }
 }
```

**Android Code:**

**In Main Activity**

```
@Override
protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

    //create TCPClient object 
    mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
        @Override
        //check whether server return message
        public void messageReceived(String message) {
            f_sensor.setText(message);
            Log.d("test1","msg rece" + message);
            //publishProgress(message);
        }
    });
    mTcpClient.run();

    return null;
}
```

**TCP Cilent**

```
public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.8.1"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 2001;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;

                }

                Log.d("test1",serverMessage);
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Android code purports to talk TCP, while your Arduino is talking Serial.  Somewhere in between is an unspecified translation which may be a source of trouble.  Your Android code looks improperly structured - you should not be creating a server object for a single use in an AsyncTask (which by default is now blocking) as you appear to be with doInBackground() but rather maintaining one within a background thread mechanism designed to *continue* running independent of others.  Finally, your Arduino code will only transmit when it receives something, and it is unclear that it is doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `serial.println` instead of `serial.write` fixes the issue.

Comment: If you are going to use a readLine() type method on the receiver, yes, you will need to transmit a terminating newline.  However, a lot of others aspects of your design remain suspicious and potential sources of future issues, too - particularly the way you are doing threading on the Android side.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no, the issue's related to this: the `.write()` function sends the ASCII code, `.print()` converts it to a string. So `Serial.write(65)` would send `A`, `Serial.print(65)` would send `6`, `5`. The `println` would also add a newline character. So the issue is they were sending the ASCII code instead of the string composed of ASCII codes.

Comment: One issue.  My point is they have others as well.

Comment: Entirely replacing the poster's answer with your own words is not appropriate, especially when you still fail to state the cause of the *specific* observed issue (no data, not unexpected data).  If you want to offer your *opinion* do so in a comment, or post your own answer which may be judged by the community on its merits.